# Beginning a sentence with "en plus"

Tags: usage, conjonctions

> Il y a plusieurs raisons à aimer le chien. D'abord, on peut jouer avec lui quand on ne sait pas quoi faire. ___, il aide à garder la maison contre des voleurs.

In the blank, we need an expression that means "moreover"/"in addition". I believe we can use "D'ailleurs"/"Par ailleurs"/"En outre"/"De plus". Can we also use "En plus"? Is it appropriate at the beginning of the sentence, and is it formal enough?

Comment: La forme correcte est: "Raison de" = Raison d'aimer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« D'ailleurs » doesn't exactly fit in this context. Given the casual tone of the sentences, « en plus » fits the bill perfectly here. « En plus » is far from a formal expression.

Il n'y a rien de mal à commencer une phrase par "en plus", **d'ailleurs**.

« D'ailleurs » ne s'emploie pas comme « deuxièmement, en plus » dans une énumération, même si la tentation est grande de mettre toutes ces expressions dans le même sac. Il s'agit plutôt de « entre parenthèses » qui se traduit par « incidentally, on a side note ».

Answer (score 0):

As a follow-up to *d'abord*, you should use *de plus* or *d'autre part*.

*En plus* is a little informal. It is commonly used when you did not think of the follow-up in the first place or when you want to keep it as a surprise. In such cases *d'abord* would be omitted.